# Internet Connection

Tags: windows, internet, alerts

I have two Internet Broadband Connections with Load Balancing Server.

Is there any tool available so I can monitor my internet connections and alert me for connection up/down status incase if any connection goes down.

Comment: Do you prefer a web site monitoring tool or a client-based tool?

Answer (score 0):

I monitor the external router IPs with [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com).  It seems to work, just allow ICMP from pingdom's public IP list, set up email and SMS alerting.  Sit back and enjoy the peace of mind.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know of a tool offhand but I'm sure you can make a quick script/program to ping a website and monitor for packet loss or timed out requests. Once it detects the timeout it could alert you somehow. I used to do this for detecting outages on load balanced web servers.

Comment: I don't have web site hosted on there IPs. Please read the question I use two internet connection in my network with load balancing. I am looking for a tool which alert me if any connection goes down.